Slack Bot Sends Message - Doesn't show up as a DM
I've created a Slack bot with the goal of having the bot send messages that show up under the "DMs" tab, but they don't show up there, they only show up under the Bot's Messages tab which I do not want.  I don't want users to go to the bot to interact if that makes sense.
I am using Postman to test and sending API calls using my bot token.
I use conversations.open to get the channel ID of the user, then use https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage to send the DM.
Things I have done:

I am using a Bot User OAuth Token.
I've toggled the checkbox on the "App Home" tab enabling the "Messages Tab".  Without this being on, my messages do not come in at all.  I don't want them showing here though.

I've also given the bot the scopes of:
channels:read
chat:write
chat:write:public
im:write
incoming:webhook
users:read
users:read.email

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
